# Finite difference aproximation - Darcy law

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, discretization

I am solving following problem:

Filtration of water can be described in bi-dimensional case by 
$$- \partial_x(K(x,y) \partial_x u ) - \partial_y (K(x,y) \partial_y u ) = 0, $$
where $u$ - water level 
$K$ - hydraulic conductivity
On uniform mesh of $N$, $K$ is defined as
\begin{align}
K(x,y) & =  \begin{cases}
    (x -0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2 - 0.04 &  \geq 0\\
     &  <0
  \end{cases}\\ 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
- \partial_x K \partial_x u  \ \ \text{is defined as} \ \  \frac{K(i+ 1/2) \partial_x u_{i+1/2} - K(i - 1/2) \partial_x u_{i - 1/2} }{h}, 
\end{align}

where $(i + 1/2)$ refers to mid-points of $(i + 1)th$ interval.

I have extended discretization into 2D case and obtained following system (not sure, if its correct)
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
   c_{i}       & c_{i+1} & 0 & d_{i+1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    c_{i-1}       & c_{i} & c_{i+1} & 0 & d_{i+1} & 0 & 0& 0 \\
0       & c_{i-1} & c_{i}  & c_{i+1} & 0 & d_{i+1}&  0 & 0\\
    d_{i-1} & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
    0  & 0  & 0 & \dots &\dots & &  c_{i-1} & c_{i} 
\end{bmatrix}
*
\begin{bmatrix}
    u_{1,1}  \\
    u_{2,1}  \\
    u_{N-1, 1}  \\
    \vdots  \\
    u_{N-1,N-1} \\
\end{bmatrix} = 0
\end{align}
where coefficients are calculated as
\begin{align}
c_i  &= + K(i -1/2,j) + K(i +1/2,j) + K(i ,j+1/2) + K(i,j-1/2)\\
c_{i + 1} &= - K(i+1/2,j) \\
c_{i- 1} &= - K(i - 1/2,j) \\
d_{i - 1} &= -  K(i,j - 1/2) \\
d_{i + 1} &= - K(i,j +1/2) \\
\end{align}

System has to satisfy following BC:
\begin{align}
\partial_x u &= 0 \ \  &\text{on} \{0,1 \} \times (0,1)\\
u &= 10 \ \  &\text{on} \{0 \} \times (0,1) \\
u &= 0 \ \  &\text{on} \{1 \} \times (0,1)
\end{align}

Can anybody give me some advices how to handle them ?

Comment: What confuses you the most about implementing these boundary conditions?

Comment: @Paul lot of staff... what I was thinking was: for Dirichlet = 0, I can just skip it from system, for neuman I am not sure what to do with them and for Dirichlet = 10 : after solving system assign them, so in this way I could preserve symmetry of system...

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/5925/3100) answer on a similar question, specifically the section **Adding a convective boundary condition**. If you set $h=0$ you have a zero-gradient condition. Maybe it is helpful.